# Sublime Text 3 подсветка html и php

Tags: php, html, sublime-text

Я хочу, чтобы в sublime text 3 у меня была подсветка всех тегов html и php. У меня не подсвечиваются `<!doctype html>`, а также `<?php >`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так у меня выглядит код в Sublime Text 3, а в Visual Studio Code эти все теги подсвечиваются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как так настроить Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть хороший вариант - colorcoder. Заходите в package control - install package и ищите. Мне очень понравился, пользуюсь все время. А вообще сдесь есть много полезных плагинов: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ4BUcogWCQ

Comment: Есть плагин, позволяющий изменить цвет только определённых тегов? Или может в настройках темы это можно изменить

Comment: Придётся походу только делать свою тему, чтобы понять как менять цвет тегов :D

Comment: @МихаилКамахин нет) Такого пока не видел. Ну там симпатичные теги)

Answer (score 0):

*colorcoder* - это кривое приложение и не работает с PHP.
Для подсветки символов **<?php** и **?>** в Sublime Text 3, нужно найти свою тему (это файл с расширением *.tmTheme).*текст курсивом*

Найти внутринего теги начала и конца кусков для обозначения подсветки

```
<dict> 
...
</dict>
        <= Пихать сюда
<dict> 
...
</dict>
```

Потом в конец файла темы вставить, где между этими тегами вот это:

```
 <dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>punctuation.section.embedded.begin.php</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#8B7AFF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>punctuation.section.embedded.end.php</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#8B7AFF</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Как добавить подсветку HTML я не в курсе, но наверно примерно так же. У меня HTML и так по умолчанию подсвечено и делать ничего не нужно.

Comment: Давно уже перестал пользоваться Sublime Text) Сейчас пользуюсь только VS Code